# speeding up JOIN by LIKE or REGEXP

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, join, mariadb-10.5

I have two tables of

```
CREATE TABLE titles
(
title_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(255),
INDEX(title),
PRIMARY KEY(title_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE phrases
(
phrase_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
phrase varchar(255),
INDEX(phrase),
PRIMARY KEY(phrase_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

I `JOIN` to find titles containing phrases as

```
SELECT a.title,b.phrase_id FROM
    titles a JOIN phrases b 
    ON a.title RLIKE CONCAT('\\b',b.phrase,'\\b')
```

since `RLIKE` does not use an index, it needs a full table scan, which is obviously slow.

I increased

```
join_buffer_size
join_buffer_space_limit
```

but not much difference.

I wonder if there is any trick to make this query faster.

Comment: Switch to a `FULLTEXT` index.  Much faster, no need to fabricate regexps.

Comment: @RickJames, it is not a frequent query. In fact, I have a table storing `title,phrase_id`. I run `INSERT INTO SELECT` rarely when `titles` or `phrases` is changed. Therefore, it is not worth `FULLTEXT`.